# How to get selected item/value in wicket CheckGroup?

Tags: wicket

How to get selected item in Wicket CheckGroup?

I am dealing with a page that has form. There are two panels with CheckGroup and DataView (this is the data that is displayed on the pannels). These panels are then wrapped into the form that is on the page. I need a way to get the selected values into the CheckGroup and process it further.

I have an panel with CheckGroup. When an item is selected I would like to add it to an collection.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: Have you read through the Wicket examples for CheckGroup?: http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/compref/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.compref.CheckGroupPage;jsessionid=D08F05A3CC409E06B39E3FFAEDDC1748?0

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `CheckGroup` model an `ArrayList`. Each `Check` in your `CheckGroup` should be the object to add to the `ArrayList` when checked. On submit of your form, you can check the `ArrayList`.

```
final ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
Car blueCar = new Car("blue");

Form<Void> form = new Form<Void>("panelForm") {
  protected void onSubmit() {
    System.out.println(cars);
  }
};
add(form);
CheckGroup<Car> group = new CheckGroup<Car>("mygroup", cars);
form.add(group);
group.add(new Check("blueCarCheck", Model.of(blueCar));
```

Comment: thanks Jered, but this doesn't work form me.  I am dealing with a page that has form. There are two panels with CheckGroup and DataView (this is the data that is displayed on the pannels). These panels are then wrapped into the form that is on the page. I need a way to get the selected values into the CheckGroup and process it further.

Comment: For some reason DataView was not working. I replaced it with ListView. Everything works now.